# how to create a custom UIImage shape in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I created an app where your goal is to dodge rocks, but when the character hits the frame of the UIImage of one of the rock obstacles(it is an irregular shaped rock) it gets destroyed. This creates the problem of dying when you hit the UIImage frame of the image and not the actual rock. Is there a way to make the UIImage not have a square shaped frame? Or do you know of any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Check out sprite kit. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html